# Delete query can't be used

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, sql-delete

When I try to do a simple query with delete, for example

```
delete from team
```

there is a syntax error on from.
Other query like select or insert work perfectly.

Comment: That expression, in isolation, is not causing the problem.  It is valid SQL.  Is there any code before or after this statement?

Comment: Based on your comments to carlton's answer: if your error shows the statement `SELECT COUNT() AS total FROM (delete from team) AS sub Dans l'instruction` as the wrong statement, then this is something your SQL client is doing. I recall phpPgAdmin doing this kind of stupid things to get the rowcount _before_ running a statement. You should always provide the **complete and exact** error message

Comment: Is there any reference table contains data of team table ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting the `;` at the end?

The query should look like:

```
DELETE FROM team;
```

NOTE: That particular deletion will remove all rows from your table.

Comment: There is the same problem even if I write ;

Comment: Can you cope&paste the error message you get, on here? @Alexis

Comment: Erreur SQL :

ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « from »
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (delete from team) AS sub
Dans l'instruction :
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (delete from team) AS sub

Comment: Is this your whole query? 'SELECT COUNT() AS total FROM (delete from team) AS sub Dans l'instruction' @Alexis

Comment: No, when I only write DELETE FROM team; but it seems that phpPgAdmin add SELECT COUNT() AS total FROM

Comment: Ok, just read the docs for Postgre. It adds that bit to count the amount of rows deleted. But I don't understand why you are getting an error. Your code should work just fine and delete everything from the table. Sorry that I couldn't help you with your problem. If I find the answer I will post here again @Alexis

Answer (score 0):

Un-check "Paginate results" and it will work.